# Connecting webcam through ip gives error "Cannot capture source"

Tags: python, opencv, camera, yolo

I have been trying to use my smartphone camera with YOLO v3 to get better frames but an error keeps on coming "Cannot capture source". I am using the IP Webcam app on my android phone.

The IP Webcam app works by connecting devices using a local network. I tried uninstalling OpenCV and then reinstalled it as it was suggested somewhere on the internet but nothing happened.
{ installation: pip install opencv-python}

I am posting a small block of code that keeps on showing an error. The whole file or code can be accessed at https://github.com/ayooshkathuria/pytorch-yolo-v3/blob/master/cam_demo.py

'''

```
    if CUDA:
            model.cuda()

        model.eval()

        videofile = 'video.avi'

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.43.1:8080/browserfs.html')

        assert cap.isOpened(), 'Cannot capture source'

        frames = 0
        start = time.time()    
        while cap.isOpened():

            ret, frame = cap.read()
```

'''

I want to use my smartphone camera as a webcam because my system lacks it.

ERROR :

```
    assert cap.isOpened(), 'Cannot capture source'
    AssertionError: Cannot capture source
```

Comment: It is unlikely that a `.html` url delivers a video stream.

Comment: it is delivering video but it too has an option for the flash player but I haven't installed it. Let me try this.

Comment: Don't confuse "shows video" with "delivers video".

Comment: @KlausD. I installed flash its running but still preview page is in HTML. http://192.168.43.1:8080/flash.html still facing the old problem. Can u suggest me another way to use a remote camera

Comment: You will have to give the stream URL, not the URL of the HTML page that displays the stream. The stream URL has to be extracted from the HTML source or by the browser's debugger.

Comment: 192.168.43.1:8080/video was the URL thanks a lot sir